# Make a matrix from last column of all files with different number of rows

Tags: r, matrix, tpm

I have a file named gene.tsv and there are 100s of folders - each containing these files. The file format is :

```
`Gene ID`          `Gene Name` Reference Strand  Start     End Coverage   FPKM   TPM
  <chr>              <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 ENSG00000187961.13 KLHL17      chr1      +      960587  965715     4.71  2.22   5.03
2 ENSG00000187583.10 PLEKHN1     chr1      +      966497  975865     3.67  2.60   5.89
3 ENSG00000187642.9  PERM1       chr1      -      975204  982093     1.09  0.445  1.01
4 ENSG00000187634.11 SAMD11      chr1      +      923928  944581     6.73  5.57  12.6 
5 ENSG00000188976.10 NOC2L       chr1      -      944204  959290    67.4  26.9   61.0 
6 ENSG00000188290.10 HES4        chr1      -      998962 1000172    27.2  13.1   29.6
```

The last column contains TPM values,
I want to make a matrix from the last column from all the samples (i.e. all the different gene.tsv files) which are in different folder (named by sample names)

The problem is each gene .tsv file contains different number of rows
For example, 1st gene.tsv contains 19645 rows, 2nd contains 19688 rows

The output should look like this: TPM values for each gene per sample..

```
             Sample1      Sample2    Sample3    Sample4     Sample5    Samle6         
A1BG      211.653339     91.35832   118.5056   227.7529    60.53333   122.0699        
A1CF        0.000000      0.00000     0.0000     0.0000     0.00000     0.0000         
A2M     21748.389142 103099.68587 18077.6432 91905.5829 71344.22858 34262.9726  
A2ML1     432.546595   3552.04679     0.0000     0.0000    13.67998  2055.6870        
A3GALT2     1.413336      0.00000     0.0000     0.0000     0.00000     0.0000         
A4GALT    731.331278    691.09973   922.3733  1083.1338   631.42933   488.1566
```

Can you please let me know how to make a matrix from the last column from every file if the row number is different?
I have tried ways but it is not working when the rows are different.
Your answer will be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: I can walk you through the problem briefly: you should do an `lapply` which takes in the sample names and uses a function (written by you) that reads that file and extracts the `tsv` column. Then use something like a `do.call(my_list, full_join, by = "ID")` to bind them together. But, as a Bioinformatician, may I ask what have you used for your quantification? Take a look at this [RNA-seq workflow from Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/rnaseqGene/inst/doc/rnaseqGene.html).

Comment: Hi.. its StingTie output..

Comment: Hi .. as suggested by you, I have made a list of all files containing Gene.ID and TPM coloumn, so my list contains 10 elements with same coloumn names: Gene.ID and TPM as I have taken 10 gene.tsv files..

Comment: Did that solve your problem? Otherwise, [take a look at `tximport`, specifically, how to impor StringTie results](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/tximport/inst/doc/tximport.html#stringtie).

Comment: No, it did not, tximport will not work without count, abundance and length coloumns, I have tried it, but it wont work for this kind of format..

Answer (score 1):

Something in the line of

```
library(foreach)
DATAf=NULL
foreach(files=c("file1.tsv","file2.tsv",...)) %do% {
DATA=read.table(file = files, sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
DATAf=rbind(DATAf,DATA[nrow(DATA),])
}
```

Comment: Hi Suppose "mysample.tsv" object contains the path to gene.tsv files , i.e.  >mysamples.tsv [1] "/space/Samples/Sample1/l.r.m.c.lib.g/k2.a/t/gene.tsv" 
 [2] "/space/Samples/Sample2/l.r.m.c.lib.g/k2.a/t/gene.tsv" 
 [3] "/space/Samples/Sample3/l.r.m.c.lib.g/k2.a/t/gene.tsv" 
 [4] "/space/Samples/Sample4/l.r.m.c.lib.g/k2.a/t/gene.tsv" 
 [5] "/space/Samples/Sample5/l.r.m2.c.lib.g/k2.a/t/gene.tsv"

Comment: No, this is not working Felix, all the FPKM and TPM values are converted to zero